# EF6 Get Record where info from two different tables equal x

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I am guessing this is a JOIN issue - which I don't understand anyway.
but I have to get a Record from EUReporteds if the Where clause is correct and if the Where clause on another table is NOT correct.

The coding I am using is truly horrific

```
do
  {
  // Get the next Unprocessed.
  if (skip == 0)
     eur = de.EUReporteds.Where(r => r.Processed == false && r.ReportProcessingCount < 11).FirstOrDefault();
  else
     eur = de.EUReporteds.Where(r => r.Processed == false && r.ReportProcessingCount < 11).OrderBy(ob => ob.id).Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault();
     // Have we personally already done this?
     pr = de.ProcessingResults.Where(p => p.UserId == CurrentUser.UserId && p.id == eur.id).FirstOrDefault();         
     skip++;
} while (pr != null || eur == null); // If so repeat
```

So what I am trying to do here is:

1. Get a record from EUReporteds
   WHERE the record has not been processed
   AND WHERE the RecordProcessingCount is less than 11
2. Check to see if this logged in user has already processed that record by
   Getting The ProcessingResults Record where The CurrentUser exists
   AND WHERE the ID of EUReporteds also exists
3. IF ProcessingResults Record Exists then we have done this record find the next until The ProcessingResults record can not be found.

Could someone please show me how to write this properly please.

Comment: "Where clause is correct and if the Where clause on another table is NOT correct."  Do you mean data exists in ProcessingResults & data doesn't exists in EUReporteds ? also you have an order by in second query ! Can you put your requirement in clear words.

Comment: Not in ProcessingResults but it is in EUReporteds

Comment: so you want the records from EUReporteds those are not processed by the current user in ProcessingResults? what about the if condition !

Comment: The if condition says if the EUReporteds Id and User Id are not there then use this EUReporteds record.

Comment: and the if condition for SrcUrl?? It would be better if you can put the retreival requirement in words. I think I would be able to answer that real quick !

Comment: Sorry you can ignore that IF statement

Comment: Get the next record from EUReported which the current user has not processed, which has the process flag set to false and which has the processing counter set lower than 11. ProcessingResults tells us if the current user has processed the record.

Comment: So its like this - get next record from EUReported that is not in processing results

Comment: ok.Let me rephrase "You need to first record from EUReportes(Processed == false && ReportProcessingCount < 11) , which is not processed by the current user(UserId == CurrentUser.UserId)" . Correct me if i am wrong !

Comment: Correct - exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(using linq):

```
var firstUnprocessedRecord = (from eur in de.EUReporteds 
                             where !eur.Processed && eur.ReportProcessingCount < 11 
                             && !(de.ProcessingResults.Any(o=>o.UserId == CurrentUser.UserId && o.id == eur.id))
                             orderby eur.id
                             select eur).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I also forgot another table that needed to be checked - which I added. It all works fine now and so much faster! Not only does it work, but thanks to you I now know how to do this for the future!